# How to set Mui theme depending on the localstorage?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, local-storage, themes, darkmode

as you can see here if you follow how to implement the switching theme functionality depending on the official docs page of mui. once you reload the site the theme go back to light theme. So **how to set the mui theme depending on the `localstorage`?**

Answer (score 2):

an easy solution would be to do something similar to the documentation [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#dark-mode-with-a-custom-palette)

Where you create your theme, you want to make something like this:

```
const ColorModeContext = React.createContext({ toggleColorMode: () => {} });

export default function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');
  useEffect(() => {
    // If there is a window
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
      // When the app loads, the mode is updated to the locally stored theme if it exists or else set to light
      setMode(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light');
  }, []);

  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // The dark mode switch would invoke this method
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        const newMode = mode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', newMode);
        setMode(newMode);
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  // Update the theme only if the mode changes
  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme({}), [mode]);

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Page />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```